# gnome-shell hang with 100%+ CPU after opening settings (17.10)

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, 17.10, display

I've just installed Ubuntu 17.10 from scratch on a 2018 ThinkPad X1 Yoga (3rd gen.), and I'm having periodic system lockups where I can't move the cursor and the fans spin up.

I'm still able to SSH in, which is how I can see `gnome-shell` is using a lot of CPU.  If I leave it for a while, the screen goes blank (along with my external display). If I kill the `gnome-shell` process, I get dropped back to text mode, but no login prompt.

It seems like this might have something to do with the presence of an external monitor, but [this answer's workaround](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969690/unable-to-change-display-settings-esp-display-scale-with-some-monitors-in-17) doesn't seem to do anything for me except trigger the hang.

Is there any way to avoid this?